# Remove properties related to Sharepoint from raw odata response

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, odata

I am using Sharepoint REST API to get/modify data in Sharepoint from NodeJS.

I am getting odata response from Sharepoint REST API and everything is working as expected.
Except one thing.

Currently I am getting response from Sharepoint REST API as below

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "https://test.sharepoint.com/_api/$metadata#SP.ApiData.Lists",
    "value": [
        {
            "odata.type": "SP.List",
            "odata.id": "https://test.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'sample-guid')",
            "odata.etag": "\"6\"",
            "odata.editLink": "Web/Lists(guid'sample-guid')",
            "AllowContentTypes": true,
            "BaseTemplate": 160,
            "BaseType": 0,
            "ContentTypesEnabled": true,
            "CrawlNonDefaultViews": false,
            "Created": "2015-05-19T11:13:46Z",
            "DefaultContentApprovalWorkflowId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "Description": "Use this list to track access requests to a site or uniquely permissioned items in the site.",
            "Direction": "none",
            "DocumentTemplateUrl": null,
            "DraftVersionVisibility": 0,
            "EnableAttachments": false,
            "EnableFolderCreation": false,
            "EnableMinorVersions": false,
            "EnableModeration": false,
            "EnableVersioning": true,
            "EntityTypeName": "AccessRequests",
            "FileSavePostProcessingEnabled": false,
            "ForceCheckout": false,
            "HasExternalDataSource": false,
            "Hidden": true,
            "Id": "sample-id",
            "IrmEnabled": false,
            "IrmExpire": false,
            "IrmReject": false,
            "IsApplicationList": false,
            "IsCatalog": false,
            "IsPrivate": false,
            "ItemCount": 1,
            "LastItemDeletedDate": "2015-05-19T11:13:46Z",
            "LastItemModifiedDate": "2015-08-04T06:57:22Z",
            "ListItemEntityTypeFullName": "SP.Data.AccessRequestsItem",
            "MajorVersionLimit": 0,
            "MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit": 0,
            "MultipleDataList": false,
            "NoCrawl": true,
            "ParentWebUrl": "/",
            "ParserDisabled": false,
            "ServerTemplateCanCreateFolders": true,
            "TemplateFeatureId: "sample-id",
            "Title": "Test Title"
        }, {
        ........
    }]
}
```

In the above response I am getting fields which are related to Sharepoint System along with fields I want.
for ex: **odata.type**, **odata.id**, **AllowContentTypes**, **BaseTemplate** etc.

How do I get the fields which I required but not the other Sharepoint related fields.

Can anybody help ?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you calling `/_api/$metadata#SP.ApiData.Lists` instead of `/_api/web/lists` ?

Comment: I am calling `/_api/web/lists` only. Its giving me response pasted above.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you could utilize `$select` query option (follow [OData Version 2.0](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#SelectSystemQueryOption) for a more details).

> Regarding `odata.type` and `odata.id` properties, since they are part
>   of *metadata* properties, you just need to specify the proper `Accept`
>   header in order to request them (eg: `accept: 
>   application/json;odata=minimalmetadata`). For a more details follow [JSON 
>   Light support
>   in REST SharePoint API released](https://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/) article.

The following example returns a specific set of List resource properties such as `AllowContentTypes` and `BaseTemplate`:

```
Endpoint URI: https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists?$select=AllowContentTypes,BaseTemplate 
Accept: application/json; odata=minimalmetadata
Method: GET
```

**Result**

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'82dcfcc5-e58c-4610-b4c3-589a7228e912')",
                    "uri": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'82dcfcc5-e58c-4610-b4c3-589a7228e912')",
                    "etag": "\"0\"",
                    "type": "SP.List"
                },
                "AllowContentTypes": true,
                "BaseTemplate": 125
            },
            //...
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I only want to get user specific fields in the response but not Sharepoint specific fields

Comment: Could you elaborate, what is ' user specific fields' and 'Sharepoint specific fields'?

Comment: And besides isn't it evident from my answer how to retrieve `odata.type, odata.id, AllowContentTypes, BaseTemplate` properties?

Comment: Actually I am trying to dynamically map Sharepoint REST API endpoints to expressjs routes. and in this case I don't know what fields user will want to have. So in URL i won't be able to use $select .